# ubuntu 10.10: How to recover accidentally deleted files?

Tags: ubuntu-10.10, file-recovery

I did

> $ sudo python
>
> dir="bla/python2.6/dist-packages"
>
> file="bla1.egg"
>
> import shutil
>
> shutil.rmtree(dir)

I should have done `shutil.rmtree(file)`

The files didn't go to the trash first. I've been searching for them with programs like Scalpel. These programs only seem to work with particular files, not a whole parent folder and all that was included in it.

I'm on ubuntu 10.10. I have as yet not touched anything. Is there a simple undo?

P.S. Is there no safety net type stuff for this in Ubuntu?

Comment: Which file system? ext3/ext4/reiserfs?

Comment: see http://superuser.com/questions/170857/ext4-undelete-utilities if it is ext4 or ext3.

Comment: Regarding your *P.S.*: You are expected to know what you're doing, especially as root.

Comment: daniel yes, but i would expect the best to make mistakes

Comment: how do i find out what file system i have

Comment: Run `df -T` or `mount`.

Comment: You can also inspect /etc/fstab to find out information about the filesystems

Comment: @ragingbull, daily backups.