# Recover Data After Formating Ubuntu OS

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, operating-systems

I was having ubuntu 10.04 on my system, and 2 partitions one with 80 GB and the Other with 70 Gb. I took a backup from 80 GB partition and saved it in 70 GB, I installed Ubuntu 11.04 on my system, when i loged in I found there is only one partition of 160GB size, I guess I have formated both the partitions and they are merged now, tried to look the size and found only 18 MBs Of Data. I was having very important data in it, Please help me out how can i recover it. Is there any way i can do that?

Comment: You have provided an NTFS/FAT link and thats Windows file system I am asking about Linux System.

Comment: My bad, you're right. Kept the wrong link. Generally though, there's not much you can do. See [here](http://superuser.com/q/170857/48078), and have a look for `ext` filesystem recovery tools.

Comment: [Backups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backup), [Backups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backup), [Backups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backup), [Backups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backup), [Backups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backup), [Backups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backup)

Answer (score 1):

Your data is most likely not recoverable.  You could try to boot from another drive and try to use a utility like [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) on it but it is far more likely that you won't be able to get anything back without Backups