# recover deleted files in linux cluster

Tags: linux, file-recovery, cluster

I just deleted some files that were very critical to my project on a linux cluster .I was wondering if there is a specific way to recover them. This is very critical and I would appreciate a detailed and quick response.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When this is all over, please consider using a revision control system. And/Or a configuration management system.

Comment: You failed to mention what filesystem you were using. `ext4`? `NTFS`? `ReiserFS`?

Comment: If it is an `ext4` partition, please see [this question](http://superuser.com/q/170857/148285) on SuperUser and [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/122305) on Unix&Linux.