# Recover deleted pictures from the partition of a formated hard drive

Tags: hard-drive-recovery, partition-recovery, recovery-partition

How do i recover the deleted pictures from the partition of a formated hard drive. I have an old hard drive that has a partition where I hid my pictures after I formated the hard drive but how do I do this?

Comment: (1) You seem to be saying that you ‘‘hid’’ your pictures on the disk *after* you formatted it.  If that’s the case, I would think recovery wouldn’t be an issue, so I guess I’m misunderstanding it — i.e., I believe that you worded it badly.  (2) You might get more specific answers to your question if you specify your operating system and file system type.  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (3) This is not the first time we’ve gotten a question like this; see [How do I recover lost/inaccessible data from my storage device?](https://superuser.com/q/241817/150988), [Recover harddrive data](https://superuser.com/q/87188/150988), [How can I recover/undelete files from an ext4 partition?](https://superuser.com/q/170857/150988), [How do I recover or “undelete” files that I accidentally deleted?](https://superuser.com/q/449550/150988), [Can overwritten files be recovered?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/149342/23408), and more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you not to touch that partition of the hard disk. Do not write any data on the disk because that could possibly overwrite your useful data. If the hard disk has a single partition, then use a different computer to download a LIVE CD/USB image and make a bootable flash drive or CD. One of the most popular images can be found here:- http://www.system-rescue-cd.org .
You can find a lot of information on that website itself as in on how to make a bootable disk.

Next, use [Testdisk](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) documentation to see the options and use the tool to retrieve your data.
[Step-by-step guide](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step) would be very useful in this regard.